# Regular expression for URL

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I have written regex to validate URL which could be either like

- example.com
- www.example.com
- http://www.example.com
- https://www.example.com

All 4 are working

Now, if I am entering in a text like (www.example.com--thisisincorrect), it is allowing me to enter and save into db

The regex that I have used is:

```
http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?
```

and

```
([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?
```

Please help!

Comment: Is that "^http(s)?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?$
" work for you?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Add `^` and `$`

```
^http(s)?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?$
```

This matches beginning of the string (`^`) and end (`$`)

Comment: Thanks It works but can you check "([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?
" this reg ex is not working for a)google.com

b)www.google.com

Comment: This doesn't work with trailing /. add '/' at the last of the url.

Comment: Has missing star `*` after final closing square bracket `]` -- as is will only allow one character after the final `/`

Fixed here: `^https?://(?:[\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(?:/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?$`

added `?:` to enable non-capturing in groups

Answer (score 93):

You don't need a regex for URLs, use `System.Uri` class for this. E.g. by using [`Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx) method for this:

```
bool isUri = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? Check this, bool isValid = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("ktp://yahoo.co.in/index.ez",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); and it returns true. Does a scheme called ktp:// exist?

Comment: @Chaitanya: according to RFC 2396, section 3.1, `ktp` is a perfectly  **valid** scheme name. E.g. a custom protocol could define this scheme.

Comment: In many cases you DO need a regex for validation of strings.  You can't pass a function into a FluentValidation rule, for example.

Comment: A regex still seems to be needed when the URI needs to be processed by software that follows an older syntax specification and thus, for example, restricts the use of hyphens in the domain name.

Comment: Seems this considers just about anything valid.

Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("anything", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
true

Comment: @AllenTellez, the expression you are testing against is a *valid* relative URI. If you want to check against an absolute URI, use `UriKind.Absolute` instead.

Comment: @mrid: `dewdwe` is a valid host name. This doesn't mean that it exists though. See RFC 2396, section 3.2.2 for details.

Comment: Both `bool isUri = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("bob", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);` and `bool isUri = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("bob", UriKind.Absolute);` return true... and "bob" isn't a valid uri.

Comment: @PKD, no the latter returns `false`. It also depends on which version of .NET you are using. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.iswellformeduristring?view=net-6.0

Comment: .Net 5, and it returns true. I set up unit tests for both Relative and Absolute, and both return true. I promise I'm not lying.

Comment: @PKD .NET 6, `true`, `false`

Comment: @Oleks - That doesn't really help if you aren't in a position to upgrade your program's code language. And having something that returns different outcomes depending on the language version seems pretty unreliable.

Comment: @PKD you, probably, referred to a framework and not the language version. If you read the link I provided you above, you might notice that there was a change starting from .NET 4.5. I'm not aware of any other changes.
But the rules for validation of a URI are quite complex to implement by yourself.
Also FYI .NET 5 you're referring to has reached the end of its support.

Answer (score 22):

Best Regex:

```
private bool IsUrlValid(string url)
{

    string pattern = @"^(http|https|ftp|)\://|[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z](:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*[^\.\,\)\(\s]$";
    Regex reg = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return reg.IsMatch(url);
}
```

Comment: Try `(http|https|ftp|)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&%\$#_]*)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\?\,\'\/\+&%\$#_]+)` instead.

Answer (score 13):

Try that:

```
bool IsValidURL(string URL)
{
    string Pattern = @"^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$";
    Regex Rgx = new Regex(Pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return Rgx.IsMatch(URL);
}
```

It will accept URL like that:

- http(s)://www.example.com
- http(s)://stackoverflow.example.com
- http(s)://www.example.com/page
- http(s)://www.example.com/page?id=1&product=2
- http(s)://www.example.com/page#start
- http(s)://www.example.com:8080
- http(s)://127.0.0.1
- 127.0.0.1
- www.example.com
- example.com

Comment: this will not work for www.google ( this is not true ) but with your code it return true.

Comment: @csharp_devloper31 This is a mandatory limitation as in the near future ".google" could become a top level domain, so the function I wrote is valid.

Comment: It's good, but it does not accept the new special charaters, like in "schüpp.ch", which is an actual website.

Answer (score 2):

when creating a regex for strict matching, you must make it sure it begins with '^' and finishes with '$'. Otherwise, the regex will see if it finds a substring which matches.

- '^' means match begin of line
- '$' means match end of line.

However, using a regex to match an URL is error prone : better rely on existing frameworks doing it better (there are a lot of potential traps in url, like parameters, unkown domains, url containing ip instead of domain....)

Answer (score 1):

**You are Looking for this**

**Without Http:**

```
@"^(www.|[a-zA-Z].)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|edu|gov|mil|net|org|biz|info|name|museum|us|ca|uk)(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\;\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$"
```

**With Http(s):**

```
@"^(((ht|f)tp(s?))\://)?(www.|[a-zA-Z].)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|edu|gov|mil|net|org|biz|info|name|museum|us|ca|uk)(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\;\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$"
```

**or**

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$";
```

Comment: thats cool. but there is a problem; if you want to use this regex with extension (.tr, .en, .cn), you will get false.

Comment: @AtakanSavaş because you should to add your desidered extension in this part: `(com|edu|gov|mil|net|org|biz|info|name|museum|us|ca|uk|tr|en|cn)`

Comment: @MarcoConcas I fixed this as you say. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I made one that finds links - works me excellently:

```
(\b(http|ftp|https):(\/\/|\\\\)[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&/~\+#])?|\bwww\.[^\s])
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
string pattern = @"^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&%\$#_]*)?$";

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

string url= txtAddressBar.Text.Trim();

if(regex.IsMatch(url)
{
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to support both http, https as optional and validate blank space is not included in url.

```
this.isValidURL = function (url) {

    if (!url) return false;

    const expression = /^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/gm;

    return url.match(new RegExp(expression));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would like to share with you advanced version of @sach4all regexp query that check all links if they have correct superdomain in case that some links only fake a correct URL address.

```
@"(www.|[a-zA-Z].)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(AAA|AARP|ABARTH|ABB|ABBOTT|ABBVIE|ABC|ABLE|ABOGADO|ABUDHABI|AC|ACADEMY|ACCENTURE|ACCOUNTANT|ACCOUNTANTS|ACO|ACTIVE|ACTOR|AD|ADAC|ADS|ADULT|AE|AEG|AERO|AETNA|AF|AFAMILYCOMPANY|AFL|AFRICA|AG|AGAKHAN|AGENCY|AI|AIG|AIGO|AIRBUS|AIRFORCE|AIRTEL|AKDN|AL|ALFAROMEO|ALIBABA|ALIPAY|ALLFINANZ|ALLSTATE|ALLY|ALSACE|ALSTOM|AM|AMERICANEXPRESS|AMERICANFAMILY|AMEX|AMFAM|AMICA|AMSTERDAM|ANALYTICS|ANDROID|ANQUAN|ANZ|AO|AOL|APARTMENTS|APP|APPLE|AQ|AQUARELLE|AR|ARAB|ARAMCO|ARCHI|ARMY|ARPA|ART|ARTE|AS|ASDA|ASIA|ASSOCIATES|AT|ATHLETA|ATTORNEY|AU|AUCTION|AUDI|AUDIBLE|AUDIO|AUSPOST|AUTHOR|AUTO|AUTOS|AVIANCA|AW|AWS|AX|AXA|AZ|AZURE|BA|BABY|BAIDU|BANAMEX|BANANAREPUBLIC|BAND|BANK|BAR|BARCELONA|BARCLAYCARD|BARCLAYS|BAREFOOT|BARGAINS|BASEBALL|BASKETBALL|BAUHAUS|BAYERN|BB|BBC|BBT|BBVA|BCG|BCN|BD|BE|BEATS|BEAUTY|BEER|BENTLEY|BERLIN|BEST|BESTBUY|BET|BF|BG|BH|BHARTI|BI|BIBLE|BID|BIKE|BING|BINGO|BIO|BIZ|BJ|BLACK|BLACKFRIDAY|BLANCO|BLOCKBUSTER|BLOG|BLOOMBERG|BLUE|BM|BMS|BMW|BN|BNL|BNPPARIBAS|BO|BOATS|BOEHRINGER|BOFA|BOM|BOND|BOO|BOOK|BOOKING|BOSCH|BOSTIK|BOSTON|BOT|BOUTIQUE|BOX|BR|BRADESCO|BRIDGESTONE|BROADWAY|BROKER|BROTHER|BRUSSELS|BS|BT|BUDAPEST|BUGATTI|BUILD|BUILDERS|BUSINESS|BUY|BUZZ|BV|BW|BY|BZ|BZH|CA|CAB|CAFE|CAL|CALL|CALVINKLEIN|CAM|CAMERA|CAMP|CANCERRESEARCH|CANON|CAPETOWN|CAPITAL|CAPITALONE|CAR|CARAVAN|CARDS|CARE|CAREER|CAREERS|CARS|CARTIER|CASA|CASE|CASEIH|CASH|CASINO|CAT|CATERING|CATHOLIC|CBA|CBN|CBRE|CBS|CC|CD|CEB|CENTER|CEO|CERN|CF|CFA|CFD|CG|CH|CHANEL|CHANNEL|CHARITY|CHASE|CHAT|CHEAP|CHINTAI|CHRISTMAS|CHROME|CHRYSLER|CHURCH|CI|CIPRIANI|CIRCLE|CISCO|CITADEL|CITI|CITIC|CITY|CITYEATS|CK|CL|CLAIMS|CLEANING|CLICK|CLINIC|CLINIQUE|CLOTHING|CLOUD|CLUB|CLUBMED|CM|CN|CO|COACH|CODES|COFFEE|COLLEGE|COLOGNE|COM|COMCAST|COMMBANK|COMMUNITY|COMPANY|COMPARE|COMPUTER|COMSEC|CONDOS|CONSTRUCTION|CONSULTING|CONTACT|CONTRACTORS|COOKING|COOKINGCHANNEL|COOL|COOP|CORSICA|COUNTRY|COUPON|COUPONS|COURSES|CR|CREDIT|CREDITCARD|CREDITUNION|CRICKET|CROWN|CRS|CRUISE|CRUISES|CSC|CU|CUISINELLA|CV|CW|CX|CY|CYMRU|CYOU|CZ|DABUR|DAD|DANCE|DATA|DATE|DATING|DATSUN|DAY|DCLK|DDS|DE|DEAL|DEALER|DEALS|DEGREE|DELIVERY|DELL|DELOITTE|DELTA|DEMOCRAT|DENTAL|DENTIST|DESI|DESIGN|DEV|DHL|DIAMONDS|DIET|DIGITAL|DIRECT|DIRECTORY|DISCOUNT|DISCOVER|DISH|DIY|DJ|DK|DM|DNP|DO|DOCS|DOCTOR|DODGE|DOG|DOHA|DOMAINS|DOT|DOWNLOAD|DRIVE|DTV|DUBAI|DUCK|DUNLOP|DUNS|DUPONT|DURBAN|DVAG|DVR|DZ|EARTH|EAT|EC|ECO|EDEKA|EDU|EDUCATION|EE|EG|EMAIL|EMERCK|ENERGY|ENGINEER|ENGINEERING|ENTERPRISES|EPOST|EPSON|EQUIPMENT|ER|ERICSSON|ERNI|ES|ESQ|ESTATE|ESURANCE|ET|ETISALAT|EU|EUROVISION|EUS|EVENTS|EVERBANK|EXCHANGE|EXPERT|EXPOSED|EXPRESS|EXTRASPACE|FAGE|FAIL|FAIRWINDS|FAITH|FAMILY|FAN|FANS|FARM|FARMERS|FASHION|FAST|FEDEX|FEEDBACK|FERRARI|FERRERO|FI|FIAT|FIDELITY|FIDO|FILM|FINAL|FINANCE|FINANCIAL|FIRE|FIRESTONE|FIRMDALE|FISH|FISHING|FIT|FITNESS|FJ|FK|FLICKR|FLIGHTS|FLIR|FLORIST|FLOWERS|FLY|FM|FO|FOO|FOOD|FOODNETWORK|FOOTBALL|FORD|FOREX|FORSALE|FORUM|FOUNDATION|FOX|FR|FREE|FRESENIUS|FRL|FROGANS|FRONTDOOR|FRONTIER|FTR|FUJITSU|FUJIXEROX|FUN|FUND|FURNITURE|FUTBOL|FYI|GA|GAL|GALLERY|GALLO|GALLUP|GAME|GAMES|GAP|GARDEN|GB|GBIZ|GD|GDN|GE|GEA|GENT|GENTING|GEORGE|GF|GG|GGEE|GH|GI|GIFT|GIFTS|GIVES|GIVING|GL|GLADE|GLASS|GLE|GLOBAL|GLOBO|GM|GMAIL|GMBH|GMO|GMX|GN|GODADDY|GOLD|GOLDPOINT|GOLF|GOO|GOODYEAR|GOOG|GOOGLE|GOP|GOT|GOV|GP|GQ|GR|GRAINGER|GRAPHICS|GRATIS|GREEN|GRIPE|GROCERY|GROUP|GS|GT|GU|GUARDIAN|GUCCI|GUGE|GUIDE|GUITARS|GURU|GW|GY|HAIR|HAMBURG|HANGOUT|HAUS|HBO|HDFC|HDFCBANK|HEALTH|HEALTHCARE|HELP|HELSINKI|HERE|HERMES|HGTV|HIPHOP|HISAMITSU|HITACHI|HIV|HK|HKT|HM|HN|HOCKEY|HOLDINGS|HOLIDAY|HOMEDEPOT|HOMEGOODS|HOMES|HOMESENSE|HONDA|HONEYWELL|HORSE|HOSPITAL|HOST|HOSTING|HOT|HOTELES|HOTELS|HOTMAIL|HOUSE|HOW|HR|HSBC|HT|HU|HUGHES|HYATT|HYUNDAI|IBM|ICBC|ICE|ICU|ID|IE|IEEE|IFM|IKANO|IL|IM|IMAMAT|IMDB|IMMO|IMMOBILIEN|IN|INC|INDUSTRIES|INFINITI|INFO|ING|INK|INSTITUTE|INSURANCE|INSURE|INT|INTEL|INTERNATIONAL|INTUIT|INVESTMENTS|IO|IPIRANGA|IQ|IR|IRISH|IS|ISELECT|ISMAILI|IST|ISTANBUL|IT|ITAU|ITV|IVECO|JAGUAR|JAVA|JCB|JCP|JE|JEEP|JETZT|JEWELRY|JIO|JLL|JM|JMP|JNJ|JO|JOBS|JOBURG|JOT|JOY|JP|JPMORGAN|JPRS|JUEGOS|JUNIPER|KAUFEN|KDDI|KE|KERRYHOTELS|KERRYLOGISTICS|KERRYPROPERTIES|KFH|KG|KH|KI|KIA|KIM|KINDER|KINDLE|KITCHEN|KIWI|KM|KN|KOELN|KOMATSU|KOSHER|KP|KPMG|KPN|KR|KRD|KRED|KUOKGROUP|KW|KY|KYOTO|KZ|LA|LACAIXA|LADBROKES|LAMBORGHINI|LAMER|LANCASTER|LANCIA|LANCOME|LAND|LANDROVER|LANXESS|LASALLE|LAT|LATINO|LATROBE|LAW|LAWYER|LB|LC|LDS|LEASE|LECLERC|LEFRAK|LEGAL|LEGO|LEXUS|LGBT|LI|LIAISON|LIDL|LIFE|LIFEINSURANCE|LIFESTYLE|LIGHTING|LIKE|LILLY|LIMITED|LIMO|LINCOLN|LINDE|LINK|LIPSY|LIVE|LIVING|LIXIL|LK|LLC|LOAN|LOANS|LOCKER|LOCUS|LOFT|LOL|LONDON|LOTTE|LOTTO|LOVE|LPL|LPLFINANCIAL|LR|LS|LT|LTD|LTDA|LU|LUNDBECK|LUPIN|LUXE|LUXURY|LV|LY|MA|MACYS|MADRID|MAIF|MAISON|MAKEUP|MAN|MANAGEMENT|MANGO|MAP|MARKET|MARKETING|MARKETS|MARRIOTT|MARSHALLS|MASERATI|MATTEL|MBA|MC|MCKINSEY|MD|ME|MED|MEDIA|MEET|MELBOURNE|MEME|MEMORIAL|MEN|MENU|MERCKMSD|METLIFE|MG|MH|MIAMI|MICROSOFT|MIL|MINI|MINT|MIT|MITSUBISHI|MK|ML|MLB|MLS|MM|MMA|MN|MO|MOBI|MOBILE|MOBILY|MODA|MOE|MOI|MOM|MONASH|MONEY|MONSTER|MOPAR|MORMON|MORTGAGE|MOSCOW|MOTO|MOTORCYCLES|MOV|MOVIE|MOVISTAR|MP|MQ|MR|MS|MSD|MT|MTN|MTR|MU|MUSEUM|MUTUAL|MV|MW|MX|MY|MZ|NA|NAB|NADEX|NAGOYA|NAME|NATIONWIDE|NATURA|NAVY|NBA|NC|NE|NEC|NET|NETBANK|NETFLIX|NETWORK|NEUSTAR|NEW|NEWHOLLAND|NEWS|NEXT|NEXTDIRECT|NEXUS|NF|NFL|NG|NGO|NHK|NI|NICO|NIKE|NIKON|NINJA|NISSAN|NISSAY|NL|NO|NOKIA|NORTHWESTERNMUTUAL|NORTON|NOW|NOWRUZ|NOWTV|NP|NR|NRA|NRW|NTT|NU|NYC|NZ|OBI|OBSERVER|OFF|OFFICE|OKINAWA|OLAYAN|OLAYANGROUP|OLDNAVY|OLLO|OM|OMEGA|ONE|ONG|ONL|ONLINE|ONYOURSIDE|OOO|OPEN|ORACLE|ORANGE|ORG|ORGANIC|ORIGINS|OSAKA|OTSUKA|OTT|OVH|PA|PAGE|PANASONIC|PARIS|PARS|PARTNERS|PARTS|PARTY|PASSAGENS|PAY|PCCW|PE|PET|PF|PFIZER|PG|PH|PHARMACY|PHD|PHILIPS|PHONE|PHOTO|PHOTOGRAPHY|PHOTOS|PHYSIO|PIAGET|PICS|PICTET|PICTURES|PID|PIN|PING|PINK|PIONEER|PIZZA|PK|PL|PLACE|PLAY|PLAYSTATION|PLUMBING|PLUS|PM|PN|PNC|POHL|POKER|POLITIE|PORN|POST|PR|PRAMERICA|PRAXI|PRESS|PRIME|PRO|PROD|PRODUCTIONS|PROF|PROGRESSIVE|PROMO|PROPERTIES|PROPERTY|PROTECTION|PRU|PRUDENTIAL|PS|PT|PUB|PW|PWC|PY|QA|QPON|QUEBEC|QUEST|QVC|RACING|RADIO|RAID|RE|READ|REALESTATE|REALTOR|REALTY|RECIPES|RED|REDSTONE|REDUMBRELLA|REHAB|REISE|REISEN|REIT|RELIANCE|REN|RENT|RENTALS|REPAIR|REPORT|REPUBLICAN|REST|RESTAURANT|REVIEW|REVIEWS|REXROTH|RICH|RICHARDLI|RICOH|RIGHTATHOME|RIL|RIO|RIP|RMIT|RO|ROCHER|ROCKS|RODEO|ROGERS|ROOM|RS|RSVP|RU|RUGBY|RUHR|RUN|RW|RWE|RYUKYU|SA|SAARLAND|SAFE|SAFETY|SAKURA|SALE|SALON|SAMSCLUB|SAMSUNG|SANDVIK|SANDVIKCOROMANT|SANOFI|SAP|SARL|SAS|SAVE|SAXO|SB|SBI|SBS|SC|SCA|SCB|SCHAEFFLER|SCHMIDT|SCHOLARSHIPS|SCHOOL|SCHULE|SCHWARZ|SCIENCE|SCJOHNSON|SCOR|SCOT|SD|SE|SEARCH|SEAT|SECURE|SECURITY|SEEK|SELECT|SENER|SERVICES|SES|SEVEN|SEW|SEX|SEXY|SFR|SG|SH|SHANGRILA|SHARP|SHAW|SHELL|SHIA|SHIKSHA|SHOES|SHOP|SHOPPING|SHOUJI|SHOW|SHOWTIME|SHRIRAM|SI|SILK|SINA|SINGLES|SITE|SJ|SK|SKI|SKIN|SKY|SKYPE|SL|SLING|SM|SMART|SMILE|SN|SNCF|SO|SOCCER|SOCIAL|SOFTBANK|SOFTWARE|SOHU|SOLAR|SOLUTIONS|SONG|SONY|SOY|SPACE|SPORT|SPOT|SPREADBETTING|SR|SRL|SRT|ST|STADA|STAPLES|STAR|STARHUB|STATEBANK|STATEFARM|STC|STCGROUP|STOCKHOLM|STORAGE|STORE|STREAM|STUDIO|STUDY|STYLE|SU|SUCKS|SUPPLIES|SUPPLY|SUPPORT|SURF|SURGERY|SUZUKI|SV|SWATCH|SWIFTCOVER|SWISS|SX|SY|SYDNEY|SYMANTEC|SYSTEMS|SZ|TAB|TAIPEI|TALK|TAOBAO|TARGET|TATAMOTORS|TATAR|TATTOO|TAX|TAXI|TC|TCI|TD|TDK|TEAM|TECH|TECHNOLOGY|TEL|TELEFONICA|TEMASEK|TENNIS|TEVA|TF|TG|TH|THD|THEATER|THEATRE|TIAA|TICKETS|TIENDA|TIFFANY|TIPS|TIRES|TIROL|TJ|TJMAXX|TJX|TK|TKMAXX|TL|TM|TMALL|TN|TO|TODAY|TOKYO|TOOLS|TOP|TORAY|TOSHIBA|TOTAL|TOURS|TOWN|TOYOTA|TOYS|TR|TRADE|TRADING|TRAINING|TRAVEL|TRAVELCHANNEL|TRAVELERS|TRAVELERSINSURANCE|TRUST|TRV|TT|TUBE|TUI|TUNES|TUSHU|TV|TVS|TW|TZ|UA|UBANK|UBS|UCONNECT|UG|UK|UNICOM|UNIVERSITY|UNO|UOL|UPS|US|UY|UZ|VA|VACATIONS|VANA|VANGUARD|VC|VE|VEGAS|VENTURES|VERISIGN|VERSICHERUNG|VET|VG|VI|VIAJES|VIDEO|VIG|VIKING|VILLAS|VIN|VIP|VIRGIN|VISA|VISION|VISTAPRINT|VIVA|VIVO|VLAANDEREN|VN|VODKA|VOLKSWAGEN|VOLVO|VOTE|VOTING|VOTO|VOYAGE|VU|VUELOS|WALES|WALMART|WALTER|WANG|WANGGOU|WARMAN|WATCH|WATCHES|WEATHER|WEATHERCHANNEL|WEBCAM|WEBER|WEBSITE|WED|WEDDING|WEIBO|WEIR|WF|WHOSWHO|WIEN|WIKI|WILLIAMHILL|WIN|WINDOWS|WINE|WINNERS|WME|WOLTERSKLUWER|WOODSIDE|WORK|WORKS|WORLD|WOW|WS|WTC|WTF|XBOX|XEROX|XFINITY|XIHUAN|XIN|XN--11B4C3D|XN--1CK2E1B|XN--1QQW23A|XN--2SCRJ9C|XN--30RR7Y|XN--3BST00M|XN--3DS443G|XN--3E0B707E|XN--3HCRJ9C|XN--3OQ18VL8PN36A|XN--3PXU8K|XN--42C2D9A|XN--45BR5CYL|XN--45BRJ9C|XN--45Q11C|XN--4GBRIM|XN--54B7FTA0CC|XN--55QW42G|XN--55QX5D|XN--5SU34J936BGSG|XN--5TZM5G|XN--6FRZ82G|XN--6QQ986B3XL|XN--80ADXHKS|XN--80AO21A|XN--80AQECDR1A|XN--80ASEHDB|XN--80ASWG|XN--8Y0A063A|XN--90A3AC|XN--90AE|XN--90AIS|XN--9DBQ2A|XN--9ET52U|XN--9KRT00A|XN--B4W605FERD|XN--BCK1B9A5DRE4C|XN--C1AVG|XN--C2BR7G|XN--CCK2B3B|XN--CG4BKI|XN--CLCHC0EA0B2G2A9GCD|XN--CZR694B|XN--CZRS0T|XN--CZRU2D|XN--D1ACJ3B|XN--D1ALF|XN--E1A4C|XN--ECKVDTC9D|XN--EFVY88H|XN--ESTV75G|XN--FCT429K|XN--FHBEI|XN--FIQ228C5HS|XN--FIQ64B|XN--FIQS8S|XN--FIQZ9S|XN--FJQ720A|XN--FLW351E|XN--FPCRJ9C3D|XN--FZC2C9E2C|XN--FZYS8D69UVGM|XN--G2XX48C|XN--GCKR3F0F|XN--GECRJ9C|XN--GK3AT1E|XN--H2BREG3EVE|XN--H2BRJ9C|XN--H2BRJ9C8C|XN--HXT814E|XN--I1B6B1A6A2E|XN--IMR513N|XN--IO0A7I|XN--J1AEF|XN--J1AMH|XN--J6W193G|XN--JLQ61U9W7B|XN--JVR189M|XN--KCRX77D1X4A|XN--KPRW13D|XN--KPRY57D|XN--KPU716F|XN--KPUT3I|XN--L1ACC|XN--LGBBAT1AD8J|XN--MGB9AWBF|XN--MGBA3A3EJT|XN--MGBA3A4F16A|XN--MGBA7C0BBN0A|XN--MGBAAKC7DVF|XN--MGBAAM7A8H|XN--MGBAB2BD|XN--MGBAI9AZGQP6J|XN--MGBAYH7GPA|XN--MGBB9FBPOB|XN--MGBBH1A|XN--MGBBH1A71E|XN--MGBC0A9AZCG|XN--MGBCA7DZDO|XN--MGBERP4A5D4AR|XN--MGBGU82A|XN--MGBI4ECEXP|XN--MGBPL2FH|XN--MGBT3DHD|XN--MGBTX2B|XN--MGBX4CD0AB|XN--MIX891F|XN--MK1BU44C|XN--MXTQ1M|XN--NGBC5AZD|XN--NGBE9E0A|XN--NGBRX|XN--NODE|XN--NQV7F|XN--NQV7FS00EMA|XN--NYQY26A|XN--O3CW4H|XN--OGBPF8FL|XN--OTU796D|XN--P1ACF|XN--P1AI|XN--PBT977C|XN--PGBS0DH|XN--PSSY2U|XN--Q9JYB4C|XN--QCKA1PMC|XN--QXAM|XN--RHQV96G|XN--ROVU88B|XN--RVC1E0AM3E|XN--S9BRJ9C|XN--SES554G|XN--T60B56A|XN--TCKWE|XN--TIQ49XQYJ|XN--UNUP4Y|XN--VERMGENSBERATER-CTB|XN--VERMGENSBERATUNG-PWB|XN--VHQUV|XN--VUQ861B|XN--W4R85EL8FHU5DNRA|XN--W4RS40L|XN--WGBH1C|XN--WGBL6A|XN--XHQ521B|XN--XKC2AL3HYE2A|XN--XKC2DL3A5EE0H|XN--Y9A3AQ|XN--YFRO4I67O|XN--YGBI2AMMX|XN--ZFR164B|XXX|XYZ|YACHTS|YAHOO|YAMAXUN|YANDEX|YE|YODOBASHI|YOGA|YOKOHAMA|YOU|YOUTUBE|YT|YUN|ZA|ZAPPOS|ZARA|ZERO|ZIP|ZIPPO|ZM|ZONE|ZUERICH|ZW)(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\;\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$
```

The list of superdomains are collected in 1 January 2019 from http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: It would make more sense to get the domain list from ICANN, set it up as a list, and do a contains check against it, than to make every url domain into a piece in this gigantic and unsustainable regex.