# Check if a string in C# is a URL

Tags: c#, string, parsing, url

This has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623007/check-if-a-string-is-a-url), but the answers are all PHP related.
Is there a similar and working solution using C#? Like a specific test class or routine?
I want to parse www.google.com or google.com or mywebsite.net etc... with or without prefixes.
Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

C# has Regex as well, but this seems simpler:

```
bool isUri = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

(Answered at [Regular expression for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717312/regular-expression-for-url))

Comment: This worked for me. The Uri.TryCreate() methods mentioned always returned NULL because the url I am pasrsing is simply something like "www.google.com". It may or may not contain HTTP or HTTPS or FTP, etc

Comment: For me does not work. I've tested "www.google.com" and will pass, next I've tested "w" and pass the same. It will does not check correctly.

Comment: @MarcoConcas has it right - something as simple as "bob" will pass right through this methodology and be called a valid uri... which it most certainly isn't.

Answer (score 3):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.validator.regex(v=vs.111).aspx

you use the above mentioned class or use the below regex and check Regex matches with your url string

```
Regex UrlMatch = new Regex(@"(?i)(http(s)?:\/\/)?(\w{2,25}\.)+\w{3}([a-z0-9\-?=$-_.+!*()]+)(?i)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
Regex UrlMatchOnlyHttps = new Regex(@"(?i)(http(s)?:\/\/)(\w{2,25}\.)+\w{3}([a-z0-9\-?=$-_.+!*()]+)(?i)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

you can also use the above regexpattern to validate the url

Comment: you need to use system.web.webpages namespace for that..

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way:

```
bool result = Uri.TryCreate(uriName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out uriResult) 
              && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp;
```

Comment: What about HTTPS and what if I don't have those prefixes? I want to check www.google.com for example or even google.com