# Remove url from a given string in C#

Tags: c#

I tried doing this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace UrlsDetector
{
    class UrlDetector
    {
        public static string RemoveUrl(string input)
        {
            var words = input;
            while(words.Contains("https://"))
            {
                string urlToRemove = words.Substring("https://", @" ");
                words = words.Replace("https://" + urlToRemove , @"");
            }
        }
        
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(UrlDetector.RemoveUrl(
                "I saw a cat and a horse on https://www.youtube.com/"));

        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

What I want to achieve is remove the entire "https://www.youtube.com/" and display "I saw a cat and a horse on".

I also want to display a message like "the sentence you input doesn't have url" if the sentence doesn't have any url.

Comment: Your example url starts with https:// but you are looking for http://. Also your code won't remove the entire url, only the http:// part. If you want to deal with any url you will need regular expressions for that.

Comment: You could use [Regex.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace); find some Regex for URLs here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717312/regular-expression-for-url

Comment: Following this tutorial might help: [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022), please take the 21 minutes to read it, it will save you hours....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using basic string manipulation will never get you where you want to be.
Using regular expressions makes this very easy for you.
search for a piece of text that looks like
`"http(s)?:\/\/\S*[^\s\.]"`:

- `http`: the text block `http`
- `(s)?`: the optional (`?`) letter `s`
- `:\/\/`: the characters `://`
- `\S*`: any amount (`*`) non white characters (`\S`)
- `[^\s\.]`: any character that is not (`^`) in the list (`[` `]`) of characters being white characters (`\s`) or dot (`\.`). This allows you to exclude the dot at the end of a sentence from your url.

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace UrlsDetector
{
  internal class Program
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(UrlDetector.RemoveUrl(
          "I saw a cat and a horse on https://www.youtube.com/ and also on http://www.example.com."));
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }

  class UrlDetector
  {
    public static string RemoveUrl(string input)
    {

      var regex = new Regex($@"http(s)?:\/\/\S*[^\s.]");
      return regex.Replace(input, "");
    }
  }
}
```

Using regular expressions you can also detect matches `Regex.Match(...)` which allows you to detect any urls in your text.

Comment: "http:(s)?:..." the first colon is wrong. Also: what if the URL is followed by another punctuation character like !;?

Comment: btw sir kevin How do use exactly the Regex.Match() to detect the url and display some message if doest have any url?

Comment: I created a quick fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zQbQYr . I added 2 wayus of doing it (via Matchand via IsMatch). IsMatch is used when just a check will do (boolean). Match() is used if you want to do more stuff with the result. your case, IsMatch will do.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a non RegEx way to do this, here you go. But the method I encoded below assumes that a URL begins with `"http://"` or `"https://"`, which means it will not work with URL's that begin with something like `ftp://` or `file://`, although the code below can be easily modified to support that. Also, it assumes the URL path continues until it reaches either the end of the string or a white space character (like a space or a tab or a new line). Again, this can easily be modified if your requirements are different.

Also, if the string contains no URL, currently it just returns a blank string. You can modify this easily too!

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str = "I saw a cat and a horse on https://www.youtube.com/";

        UrlExtraction extraction = RemoveUrl(str);
        Console.WriteLine("Original Text: " + extraction.OriginalText);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Url: " + extraction.ExtractedUrl);
        Console.WriteLine("Text: " + extraction.TextWithoutUrl);
    }

    private static UrlExtraction RemoveUrl(string str)
    {       
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        {
            return new UrlExtraction("", "", "");
        }

        int startIndex = str.IndexOf("https://", 
                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        if (startIndex == -1)
        {
            startIndex = str.IndexOf("http://", 
                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }

        if (startIndex == -1)
        {
            return new UrlExtraction(str, "", "");
        }

        int endIndex = startIndex;
        while (endIndex < str.Length && !IsWhiteSpace(str[endIndex])) 
        {           
            endIndex++;
        }

        return new UrlExtraction(str, str.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex), 
            str.Remove(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex));
    }

    private static bool IsWhiteSpace(char c)
    {
        return 
            c == '\n' || 
            c == '\r' || 
            c == ' ' || 
            c == '\t';
    }

    private class UrlExtraction
    {
        public string ExtractedUrl {get; set;}
        public string TextWithoutUrl {get; set;}
        public string OriginalText {get; set;}

        public UrlExtraction(string originalText, string extractedUrl, 
            string textWithoutUrl)
        {
            OriginalText = originalText;
            ExtractedUrl = extractedUrl;
            TextWithoutUrl = textWithoutUrl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A simplified version of what you're doing. Instead of using `SubString` or `IndexOf`, I split the input into a list of strings, and remove the items that contain a URL. I iterate over the list in reverse as removing an item in a forward loop direction will skip an index.

```
    public static string RemoveUrl(string input)
    {
        List<string> words = input.Split(" ").ToList();
        for (int i = words.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {
            if (words[i].StartsWith("https://")) words.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        return string.Join(" ", words);
    }
```

This methods advantage is avoiding `SubString` and `Replace` methods that essentially create new Strings each time they're used. In a loop this excessive string manipulation can put pressure on the Garbage Collector and bloat the Managed Heap. A `Split` and `Join` has less performance cost in comparison especially when used in a loop like this with a lot of data.

@Moshi is correct with large amounts of data, so this is more of a Production Code Base example:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static LinkedList<T> RemoveAll<T>(this LinkedList<T> list, Predicate<T> match)
    {
        if (list == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
        }
        if (match == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("match");
        }
        var count = 0;
        var node = list.First;
        while (node != null)
        {
            var next = node.Next;
            if (match(node.Value))
            {
                list.Remove(node);
                count++;
            }
            node = next;
        }
        return list;
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var s= "I saw a https://www.youtube.com/cat and a https://www.youtube.com/horse on https://www.youtube.com/";

        //Uncomment for second run 
        //s= @"I saw a https://www.youtube.com/cat and a https://www.youtube.com/horse on https://www.youtube.com/
        //but it doesnt work
        //what I want to achieve is remove the entire https://www.youtube.com/ and display I saw a cat and a horse on
        //I also want to display a message like the sentence you input doesn't have url if the sentence doesn't have any url.";

        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

        watch.Start();
        var resultList = RemoveUrl(s);
        watch.Stop(); Debug.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());

        watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
        var wordsLL = new LinkedList<string>(s.Split(' '));
        var result = string.Join(' ', wordsLL.RemoveAll(x => x.StartsWith("https://")));
        watch.Stop(); Debug.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());
       }
 }
```

**var s one line:**
watch.Elapsed = {00:00:00.0116388}
watch.Elapsed = {00:00:00.0134778}

**var s multilines:**
watch.Elapsed = {00:00:00.0013588}
watch.Elapsed = {00:00:00.0009252}

Comment: It won't be good choice because `RemoveAt` will take `O(n)` time. see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#remarks)

Answer (score 1):

Better way to use, split and `StringBuilder`. Code will be look like this. `StringBuilder` is optimized this kind of situation.

Pseudocode:

```
    var words = "I saw a cat and a horse on https://www.youtube.com/".Split(" ").ToList();
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var word in words){
        if(!word.StartsWith("https://")) sb.Append(word + " ");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
```